# Docker installation on Windows 10

Tags: docker, installation, docker-for-windows

I am trying to install Docker on Windows 10 Enterprise Edition but got following exception.

**Installation failed**

```
The Server service is not started.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoMachineInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue)
   at CommunityInstaller.CreateGroupAction.<DoAsync>b__33_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<HandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<ProcessAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
```

Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Does your windows 10 machine has Hyper-V enabled ?

Answer (score 12):

you have to go to `services` app and start `server` service if it disabled like the pic[image]

you should start by double click on `server` service and choose automatic and press okay
[image]

and it will work with u

Answer (score 1):

There can be any issues.
One issue could because the windows service `Server` was disabled. 
FIX: Enable it and start on Service App.